# Module doesn't work when placed in `app/code`

Tags: magento2, module, composer

i'm editing a Magento 2 module. If i install the module via `composer require`, then run all the necessary commands, the module works.

If i manually copy the module files from `vendor/{vendorname}/{modulename}` to `app/code/{vendorname}/{modulename}`, then uninstall the `vendor` module via composer+all the necessary commands, then i enable the module present in `app/code` with the necessary commands, this is the result:
[image: error in dashboard]

And this is the resulting `system.log`:

```
[2022-10-21T14:57:47.998332+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Error: Class "Mynamespace\Helper\Data" not found in /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject()
#1 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create()
#2 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get()
#3 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create()
#4 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/BlockFactory.php(44): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create()
#5 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(272): Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory->createBlock()
#6 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(252): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->getBlockInstance()
#7 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(229): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->createBlock()
#8 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(134): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->generateBlock()
#9 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(93): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->process()
#10 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(365): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process()
#11 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#12 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent()
#13 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#14 /var/www/magento2-domain/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(32): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#15 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements()
#16 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#17 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#18 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(271): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#19 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(896): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
#20 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/module-cms/Helper/Page.php(216): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock()
#21 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Index/Index.php(74): Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage()
#22 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index->execute()
#23 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent()
#24 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#25 /var/www/magento2-domain/generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#26 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(111): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->execute()
#27 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch()
#28 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent()
#29 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#30 /var/www/magento2-domain/generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(32): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#31 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(245): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch()
#32 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(212): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->getActionResponse()
#33 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(147): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest()
#34 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch()
#35 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent()
#36 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(99): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#37 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch()
#38 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(75): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#39 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch()
#40 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#41 /var/www/magento2-domain/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#42 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch()
#43 /var/www/magento2-domain/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#44 /var/www/magento2-domain/pub/index.php(30): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run()
#45 {main} [] []
```

From this log it seems that magento cannot find one of my module's classes, as if the class has not been autoloaded.

So my question is:
**How is it possible that the EXACT same module works when placed in the `vendor` folder via composer, but doesn't work when manually placed under `app/code` ??**

The module is evidently **working** when placed in `vendor`, hence **the code is correct**.

**Isn't `app/code` meant to be used for the live development of modules?? Am i missing something?**

---

Please note: after i moved the module to `app/code` i ran the following commands:

```
  composer install
  composer dump-autoload
  bin/magento module:status
  bin/magento module:enable Companyname_Modulename --clear-static-content
  bin/magento setup:upgrade
  bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: as i said in the post, it seems that the autoloading of classes **doesn't** work when the code is placed in `app/code`. is that correct? how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules from `vendor` can move to `app/code`, and it works fine.

Make sure you set the correct namespace (folders name) with **case sensitive** for vendorname and modulename in app/code:

The correct namespace gets from `componentName` param in `vendor/vendorname/modulename/registration.php`, or some path related like  `vendor/vendorname/src/modulename/registration.php`, it depend on how the vendor build the structure.

eg: `vendor/aetonsi/catalog/registration.php` has `componentName` is `Aetonsi_Catalog`, you should change to `app/code/Aetonsi/Catalog`

Comment: dammit it works... the composer package has a different name than the namespace used internally (company/vendor name matches, but package is named differently)..... could you please kindly point me to a documentation of some sort where you found this information? i didn't read this **anywhere** when researching... Thank you !!!

Comment: I earned this knowledge from reading Magento core code, Magento devdocs,... with working experience. Now you know all about that! If you have any issues, post them to this Magento Stack Exchange, I and more people here can help.